# SenseNet error at user login: System.Web.HttpException

Tags: asp.net, .net, sensenet

We're getting an error when users try to sign into Sensenet; they get the following error:

System.Web.HttpException

The site has encountered a problem and cannot serve you the requested resource.

Exception message

The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). 
 at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child) 
 at SenseNet.Portal.UI.ContentListViews.ViewFrame.LoadSelectedView(String name) in c:\Builds\15\SenseNet\630\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Portal\UI\ContentListViews\ViewFrame.cs:line 242 
 at SenseNet.Portal.UI.ContentListViews.ViewFrame.CreateChildControls() in c:\Builds\15\SenseNet\630\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Portal\UI\ContentListViews\ViewFrame.cs:line 174 
 at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() 
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() 
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Exception Source

System.Web

Stack trace

at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child) at SenseNet.Portal.UI.ContentListViews.ViewFrame.LoadSelectedView(String name) in c:\Builds\15\SenseNet\630\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Portal\UI\ContentListViews\ViewFrame.cs:line 242 at SenseNet.Portal.UI.ContentListViews.ViewFrame.CreateChildControls() in c:\Builds\15\SenseNet\630\Sources\Source\SenseNet\Portal\UI\ContentListViews\ViewFrame.cs:line 174 at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I'm a SysAdmin, not an ASP dev, so I'm not sure where to even begin to start looking!

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems there is a content list on either the login page itself or (more likely) on the main page that the users visit first. And one of the views under that list is corrupted - or if there is no view under that list at all, than it can be a global list view somewhere in /Root/System/SystemPlugins/ListViews.

The point is, you have to repair this view, maybe it was edited manually recently and contains some invalid asp.net markup.

Comment: Hi, thanks. No changes were made except that a new SSL certificate was installed. Could that have anything to do with the error?